# Pyspark Count the number of string appearance

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark. I want to find the number of string "NA" for each column. The code below has a problem. I want to count the string with "NA", but the code below will also count "NAN", "NANN. Is there a way to change to exactly equal?

```
names = weatherData.schema.names
for name in names:
    print(name + ': ' + str(weatherData.where(df[name].has("NA")).count()))
```

Comment: change to `where(df[name] == "NA")`

Comment: @jxc Thanks, why not post as a answer?